# Incorrect display of children's models on the form in django

Tags: python, django

I tried to make a creation form for vacancy on my job search site, but i faced with problem. I have User model, company model and vacancy model. They are inherited by foreignkeys. And the problem is that user can use all companies for creation a vacancy instead of created by this user companies(User can create several companies). I tried to change creation form and view by filtering, but it didn't work out for me. I am new at django and i dint find anything to resolve my problem.

Model of company:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(('Title of Shop'), blank=True, max_length=255)
    info = models.TextField(('Information about Shop'), null=True, blank=True)
    
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

Model of vacancy:

```
class Vacancies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(('Title of Vacancy'), blank=True, max_length=255)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='363')
    description = models.TextField(('Information about Vacancy'), null=True, blank=True)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

Create vacancy view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createVacancy(request):
    form = VacanciesForm()
    cities = City.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VacanciesForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():           
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form': form, 'cities': cities}
    return render(request, 'vacancy_form.html', context)
```

Vacancy form:

```
class VacanciesForm(ModelForm):
    

    class Meta:
        model = Vacancies
        fields = '__all__'
```

What do I need to change to get the correct display of companies in the vacancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work:

**views**

```
def createVacancy(request):

    cities = City.objects.all()
    
    form = VacanciesForm(data=request.POST, request=request)
        
    if form.is_valid(): 
                  
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    
    
    context = {'form': form, 'cities': cities,}
    return render(request, 'vacancy_form.html', context)
```

**forms**

```
class VacanciesForm(ModelForm, forms.Form):   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(VacanciesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employer'].queryset = EmployerCard.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class Meta:
        model = Vacancies
        
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_vacancy(request):
    user = request.user
    cities = City.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VacanciesForm(data=request.POST, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():           
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form': form, 'cities': cities}
    return render(request, 'vacancy_form.html', context)
```

Also you can use in view:

```
def create_vacancy(request, logined_user_id):
    vacancies = Vacancies.objects.filter(owner=logined_user_id)
    ...
```

And you can try some logic here:

```
class VacanciesForm(ModelForm):
    vacancies = [some_logic]

    class Meta:
        model = Vacancies
        fields = '__all__'
```

Finally, you can read docs:
[modelforms](https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)